# How to simulate mouse click using c# by send/postmessage win32api in a game?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

I want to simulate a mouse click in a minimized very old game(early years around 2000) using c# .net framework 3.5, by calling sendMessage/postMessage to win32api.

I've done many tests and so far here are the facts:

1. I got both `SendInput` and `mouse_event` to work properly. However it needs the window not to be covered by other window.
2. I can send Char to the minimized game window by `var result = SendMessage(hWnd, WM_CHAR, (IntPtr)'A', IntPtr.Zero);`, the returned result is 0.
3. It seems WM_MOUSEMOVE works by `SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));`
4. However the game won't work if call `var result = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));`, neither work if call `var result = PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));`, the returned result is 1.

Then I tried using Spy++ to see what happend if I click in the game, and here's the log (sorry Imgur and Stackoverflow won't be able to upload the image, so I post it on X):
https://twitter.com/SunPengfei51/status/1752265711945453758

I manually simulate all the messages by the following codes, then use Spy++ to monitor if my simulation generates the same logs.

```
    Point point = new Point(89, 259);
    Point p = new Point(796, 744);

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(p.X, p.Y));
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, hWnd, makeLParam(1, (int)WM_LBUTTONDOWN));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONDOWN, (IntPtr)MK_LBUTTON, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_NCHITTEST, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(p.X, p.Y));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETCURSOR, hWnd, makeLParam(1, (int)WM_LBUTTONUP));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_LBUTTONUP, IntPtr.Zero, makeLParam(point.X, point.Y));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Here's the log, as far as I can tell, my simulate generates exatly the same messages.

https://twitter.com/SunPengfei51/status/1752265295505637612

Please let me know what I should do from here to achieve the goal. Thanks!

It's not a duplicate question. 1 Evidence showed that my target can be achieved. 2 The focus of this question is more to discuss why even Spy++ message logs are the same, the program does not respond accordingly.

Comment: You can't guarantee that this game can also respond to click events when running in the background, right?

Comment: @shingo No I can't, but I've done all my above test after bringing the target game window to foreground. I've heard that years ago someone uses post message to simulate clicks in this game. What I want to know is the last part of this question, that even I've managed to make all the messages are the same with the logs for real click shown in Spy++, and it still not works. Does that mean I did my part right, but the game does not rely on any click messages?

Comment: If the game is in the foreground, does your simulation work?

Comment: @shingo All my tests and question description are made when the game is in the foreground. And as described above, only the simulation of clicks do not work.

Comment: The proposed duplicate doesn't waste time and cuts right down to the cheese: *"You cannot do that."* It spends a lot of time explaining why that is and concludes with *"Cheating is hard. **Really** hard. And your problem doesn't have an easy solution."* Those are the two key takeaways. If you insist on wanting to cheat, you'll have to get invested, *really* invested.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you, I've read the duplicate question very carefully before asking my question. I'm not aiming to cheat but the technical part, mostly out of curiosity. (I've already manage to "cheat" if I want, just by simply using sendInput or mouse_event). I'm 100% sure that old game is cheatable because that's what it's famous for. I just want to write my own cheat codes, and get to know each tech details. it's kind of like a childhood dream to me.

Comment: As my simple rebuttal to that duplicate answer, yes you can do it in this particular old game I'm targeted at. It's been done by others. I've left message to other programmers in very old websites and left url lead to this question. But it's unlikely they'd get that message after so many years.